# Code not executed when Android Dialog box answered too quickly (race condition)

Tags: android, dialog, race-condition

In my android app, I have a dialog box which has code like this:

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    dialog.cancel();
    doStuff();
    doMorestuffThatTakesTime();
}
})
```

The thing I noticed is, that if I press the 'Yes' button very quickly, code in the doStuff() doesn't get executed. I wondered if the dialog.cancel() order had anything to do with it, but the problem exists even with it moved to the end and also removed altogether.

It feels like some sort of race condition, but what is the problem and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning. Yet more proof of concept code:
You could try launching a thread in on click as in:

```
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {               //cancels itself?
            Thread thread= new Thread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000); //<== mimic time intensive task
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){             
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG,"done");
                    myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            });
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }       
    });
```

And trap the message in the single Activity Handler:

```
private Handler myHandler= new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void  handleMessage(Message msg){        
        switch(msg.what){
            case 0:
                this.removeMessages(0);
                Log.d(TAG,"gotit");
             break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

This will NOT work if you try to touch the UI from the new thread.